# select next element CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

i have 2 div elements in html :

```
<body>
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

I want to hide div elements after div with `id="one"` from CSS, I tried this :

`#one:after{display:none}`

This doesn't work any other way to do?

Comment: The title says “next element”, the text says “div elements after div with `id="one"`”. Which one is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, `:after` pseudo doesn't do that, you need to use

```
#one + div {
   display: none;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xh89T/)

And if you want to hide **ALL** `div` followed by `#one` you will have to use

```
#one ~ div {
   display: none;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xh89T/1/)

Comment: Mahender Singh can you then please accept the answer if this is what you are looking for ? Pleasssssse

Answer (score 1):

`:after` applies to *generated* content. You want [the adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators):

```
#one + * {

}
```

Comment: `*` will hide all elements

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact position of the child element (like in you case its 2nd child), you can use nth-child pseudo class

```
div:nth-child(2)
{
    display:none;
}
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/ankur1990/HDq2T/